# Operation CTL_BOOTSTRAP canceled during phase 0, error = ORA-408

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, dataguard

I am currently testing a data guard environment.
In the alert.log of the broker I always see the following message after a switchover:

> 2019-05-23 08:08:54.716 7fffffff           0 Operation CTL_BOOTSTRAP
>   canceled during phase 0, error = ORA-408

The whole starting data guard broker bootstrap log looks as follows:

Broker Configuration File Locations:

> dg_broker_config_file1 =
>   "D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT"
>
> dg_broker_config_file2 = "D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE
>   \DR2TEST.DAT"

```
2019-05-23 08:08:50.642                      DMON: Attach state object
2019-05-23 08:08:50.645                      DMON: Opening configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT' with blocksize 4096
2019-05-23 08:08:50.648                      DMON: Successfully opened configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT'
2019-05-23 08:08:50.656                      DMON: Opening configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR2TEST.DAT' with blocksize 4096
2019-05-23 08:08:50.659                      DMON: Successfully opened configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR2TEST.DAT'
2019-05-23 08:08:50.671                      DMON: Opening configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT' with blocksize 4096
2019-05-23 08:08:50.674                      DMON: Successfully opened configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT'
2019-05-23 08:08:50.688                      DMON: rfafoGetLocks reinitializing dubious PMYSHUT lock value block contents: sts=0, flags=0x0, spare1=0x0, spare2=0x0, cksm=0x0, rndm=0x0
2019-05-23 08:08:50.690                      DMON: Broker state reconciled, version = 0, state = 00000000
2019-05-23 08:08:50.692                      DMON: Broker State Initialized
2019-05-23 08:08:50.694                            Version = 1
2019-05-23 08:08:50.696                            State = 00000000
2019-05-23 08:08:50.698                      DMON: Entered 
rfm_get_chief_lock() for CTL_BOOTSTRAP, reason 2
2019-05-23 08:08:50.700 7fffffff           0 DMON: Entered 
rfm_get_chief_lock() for CTL_BOOTSTRAP, reason 0
2019-05-23 08:08:53.722                      INSV: Opening configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT' with blocksize 4096
2019-05-23 08:08:53.727                      INSV: Successfully opened configuration file 'D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT'
**2019-05-23 08:08:54.716 7fffffff           0 Operation CTL_BOOTSTRAP canceled during phase 0, error = ORA-408**
2019-05-23 08:08:54.719 7fffffff           0 DMON: start task execution: broker initialization
2019-05-23 08:08:54.721                      DMON: Boot configuration (0.0.0), loading from "D:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\12.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\DR1TEST.DAT"
2019-05-23 08:08:54.756                      DMON: Verifying broker service TEST_DGB
2019-05-23 08:08:54.759                      DMON: Verifying configuration service TEST_CFG
2019-05-23 08:08:54.761                      DMON: Broker service not registered
2019-05-23 08:08:54.764                      DMON: Adding broker service...
2019-05-23 08:08:54.766                      DMON: Configuration service not registered
2019-05-23 08:08:54.769                      Adding configuration service...
2019-05-23 08:08:54.772                      DMON: Registering 2 service/s with listener(s)
2019-05-23 08:08:54.776                      DMON: Executing SQL [ALTER SYSTEM REGISTER]
2019-05-23 08:08:54.780                      SQL [ALTER SYSTEM REGISTER] Executed successfully
05/23/2019 08:08:54
```

The switchover is successful at all, but I am not sure how to think about the displayed error. After doing some research, I found it might be related to some compatibility issue. But the compatibility is set to 12.2.0.
I am testing with the base version of the oracle database 12.2.0.

I would appreciate, if anyone could help me!